# How do I blur a view underneath with a custom radius (not using UIBlurEffect) in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiblureffect

I'm trying to create a frosted glass effect in SwiftUI. I have a background image and a rectangle on top. I want to blur the image where the rectangle is. I'm essentially trying to achieve a glass morphism look and I haven't found any way to do it online yet. I can't use a UIBlurEffect because I don't believe there's any way to set the blur radius which I need to able to set. I also can't use the blur modifier on the rectangle as that just blurs the rectangle but not the image underneath. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Code I have so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            
            Image("background")
            
            Image("background")
                .frame(width: 300, height: 180)
                .mask(Rectangle().frame(width: 300, height: 180))
                .blur(radius: 5, opaque: true)
                .brightness(0.2)
                .offset(offset)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            self.offset = gesture.translation
                        }
                )
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ZStack of the same two Views, one blurred, one not. You'll also apply `.mask` to the top view to confine the blur to the zone you want.

You'll want to use

```
.blur(radius: someValue, opaque: true)
.brightness(someValue)
```

and possibly a `blendMode` and third layer in that ZStack of `Color(.systemBackground)` with some opacity.

Be sure to test the effect in light and dark.

Comment: This is close but it didn't work exactly as I want it to. I need to be able to move around the rectangle and it blurs over the area of the image that I drag it over, like frosted glass. With the code I have right now, when I move it over another part of the image, the part of the image that it originally was at moves with it. I've edited my question to include the code I have at the moment.

Comment: That's a new requirement. For your gesture, you might want to be doing a += type approach. You'd have a GestureState variable that tracks the extent of the translation and an @State variable that is modified at the end of the gesture to save state.

Comment: For the image, you can do many approaches. You can change the mask location. You can use white and black colors to create a luminance mask. (.luminanceToAlpha)

Comment: Right now you're applying the offset to the image and not the mask.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 simple options to have a simple blurred view in SwiftUI:

---

Option  1:

#### Using iOS Materials (from iOS 15)

in iOS, there are predefined blurred views called **Material** that is exactly what is you are looking for. In SwiftUI you can use them like:

```
.background(.ultraThinMaterial)
```

[image: Materials]

---

Option  2:

#### Using The Visual Effect View (for UIKit)

You can bring the prefect `UIVisualEffectView` from the UIKit:

```
VisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
```

With this tiny struct:

```
struct VisualEffectView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var effect: UIVisualEffect?
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIVisualEffectView { UIVisualEffectView() }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) { uiView.effect = effect }
}
```

[image: VEV Demo]

### <sub>The above example uses a dark version, you can use a lighter version for your usecase</sub>

Option  3:

#### Using the `blur` modifier

Just add `.blur()` modifier on anything you need to be blurry like:

```
Image("BG")
   .blur(radius: 20)
```

[image: Blur Demo]
<sub>Note the top and bottom of the view</sub>

For your use case, you may want to duplicate the image and blur the top one to make the glass illusion.